# Numpy - calculate mean of groups

Tags: python, numpy, average

I have a an array of shape (N, 3) like this one for instance:

```
arr = np.array(
  [
    [0,1,1], 
    [0,1,2], 
    [2,2,2]
  ]
)
```

I want to group this array by the two first columns to obtain an array like this

```
grouped_arr = np.array([[[0,1,1], [0,1,2]], [[2,2,2]]])
```

Finally I would like to get only one element by group while the third column would be the mean of the group third column

```
final_array = np.array([[0,1,1.5], [2,2,2]])
```

I am trying something but not sure if it's correct and if it's an efficient way to achieve it:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0,1,1], [0,1,2], [2,2,2]])

stacked = np.vstack((arr[:,0], arr[:,1])).transpose()
uniques_values = np.unique(stacked, axis=0)

groups = []
for v in uniques_values:
    groups.append(arr[v])

final_arr = []
for group in groups:
    mean = np.mean(group[:,2], axis=0)
    final_arr.append(np.array([group[0][0], group[0][1], mean]))

print(final_arr)

>>>[array([0. , 1. , 1.5]), array([2., 2., 2.])]
```

I am looking for a reliable and efficient suggestion. In my real data the dtype is float

Comment: You're talking about columns when you really mean rows.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I did not had time yet to test and  fully understand your answer. I am sure your answer is good though so I'll accept it and test it next week. Thank you

Comment: If something does not work, you can leave a comment and I'll be happy to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a ragged array in numpy. That's what lists are for. Instead of separating the data into groups, you can identify the locations of the groups, and operate them using the aggregation functions that ufuncs provide.

Specifically, you can use `np.add.reduceat` to construct the means once you identify the indices of the group starts. Groups start when a either number in the first two columns does not match what is in the previous row:

```
mask = (arr[:-1, :2] != arr[1:, :2]).any(1)
group_indices = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True, mask])
```

Now taking the mean is straightforward:

```
sums = np.add.reduceat(arr[:, -1], group_indices, axis=0)
lengths = np.diff(np.r_[group_indices, len(arr)])
means = sums / lengths
```

To construct the output, you just need the first two columns of the array at the start indices of each group concatenated with the means (transposed to be a column):

```
result = np.concatenate((arr[group_indices, :2], means[:, None]), axis=1)
```

Comment: The only issue I have found with your answer it that the array needs to be sorted by the two first columns. I achieved it by doing `sorted_arr = arr[np.lexsort((arr[:,1], arr[:,0]))]` Can you confirm?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar. That is correct. I made that assumption that your data was sorted based on the example, and that definitely is a requirement. lexsort is a good way to do it.